# How do I change the default blockchain Database download location for NXT?

Tags: blockchain, nxt

I'm testing out the nxt client and was wondering how do i change the default database download location? Its currently downloading to the current folder (nxt_db).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From nxtforum.org "Move blockchain location" at http://nxtforum.org/nrs-client-how-to-help/move-blockchain-location/

> look in /conf/nxt-default.properties.
>
> In the #### DATABASE #### section, you will find by default
>
> > # The nxt_db folder is expected to be in the current working directory, will be created if missing.
> >
> > nxt.dbUrl=jdbc:h2:nxt_db/nxt;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
>
> NRS will create the database folder in D:/nxt_db.
>
> You can also leave nxt-default properties with default values, and create a user properties file called "nxt.properties" in the same /conf folder. Any values in nxt.properties will override defaults in nxt-default.properties, so a nxt.properties file defining nxt.dbUrl will work the same as the previous edit.

Hope this helps.